# Pandas: How to calculate summation of value based on another dateframe's datetime interval

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Suppose I have two dataframe `df1` and `df2`

In `df1`

   `date                 value
0  2018-01-23 10:00:00  10
1  2018-01-23 11:00:00  20
2  2018-01-23 12:00:00  30`

In `df2`

   `date                 value
0  2018-01-23 10:02:00  10
1  2018-01-23 10:03:00  20
2  2018-01-23 10:04:00  30
3  2018-01-23 10:05:00  40
4  2018-01-23 10:06:00  50
5  2018-01-23 11:07:00  50
...`

Update:

I want to calculate the summation of `df2.value` based on the interval selected by `df1.date.iloc[n-1]` and `df1.date.iloc[n]`. I can get index of `df2.date` by `IntervalIndex` but unable to select the value inside each interval.

Comment: Tl;dr, build an IntervalIndex from the df.date and df.date.shift(-1).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you for pointing out the direction. After using `IntervalIndex` how do I calculate the summation of 'df2.value' based on IntervalIndex? For example, at [2018-01-23 10:00:00, 2018-01-23 11:00:00], summation of `df2.value` would be 150. I am still not sure how to select the time range using IntervalIndex. Shouldn't it be `df2.loc[idx.get_indexer(df2.date), "value"]`  where `idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1.date, df.date.shift(1))`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I found your link does not work, there are skipped `df1.value` and I don't need to join two dataframes.